# Can one make internal links work within a client-side-generated HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

Situation: for various reasons (mainly, that it will be used at times in situations where the Internet is not availble), some JavaScript-heavy HTML I am building has to be able to run at times strictly on the client, with no server involved. For the most part, I've been able to come up with workarounds that allow pages from this site to be saved by the usual browser 'Save Page As' mechanisms, embed all the pieces they need, and massage paths to refer where I want them to (on the local machine) when the browser isn't smart enough to fix the URL (which is more often than I might have thought).

One piece I haven't been able to solve yet, though: each main page can open a help page in a new tab/window. To do that, I embed the content of the help page in the main saved page. Then I can use `helpWindow.document.write(helpContent)` to open that. Problem: as far as the browser is concerned, the help page ends up with the same URL as the original page, so I can't effectively use page-internal links on that page: it tries to load the main saved page if you click one!

For example: `<a name="target" />` ... `<a href="#target">link</a>` in the help page: if you click "link", the browser loads the main saved page, rather scrolling the help page.

My temporary workaround is to strip these links when I have to operate in this environment, but I'd sure rather have a way to make them work. Any suggestions? Suggestions could include an entirely different way to open a help page. I'd rather not use iframes, though, I'd really like it to stay in a separate tab/window.

Comment: You could use the tabs within the HTML/JavaScript context... meaning, the page itself has a tab bar (or maybe adds one when/if needed), and you hide or show DIVs depending on the tab/link that's clicked.

Comment: Just possibly. I believe it would solve my internal linking problem only if it's impossible to have both the help content and the regular page visible at once (because scrolling via a link would scroll the whole page). Also, I like the option of this being in another window (or tearaway tab) so that users who *want* to see both at once can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll to the bookmark with JavaScript with `element.scrollIntoView()`:

```
function goToBookmark(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    e.returnValue = false;
    var bookmarkName = this.href.replace(/^#/, "");
    var bookmark = document.getElementsByName(bookmarkName)[0];
    if (bookmark)
    {
        bookmark.scrollIntoView();
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++)
{
    var link = document.links[i];
    if (/^#/.test(link.href))
    {
        link.onclick = goToBookmark;
    }
}
```

Or, if you are using jQuery:

```
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var bookmark = $("a[name=" + this.href.replace(/^#/, "") + "]")[0];
    if (bookmark) {
        bookmark.scrollIntoView();
    }
});
```

Comment: I finally got back to this recently, and (while this isn't quite what I did) the solution is along these lines. I ended up putting the help within a jQuery dialog and then using a technique like this within that, so I could scroll help text and leave the rest of the page alone.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

In particular try: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TiddlyWiki

(Sorry, that this doesn't answer your question, but if you have not see those, maybe you can get ideas from them.)

Edit:

I tried this out a bit, and that's really strange! It almost seems like a bug to me. Do all browsers do this?

A solution could be to use `ID` instead of `A NAME` (which BTW you can/should do even if you wanted to link by anchor fragment) and then use

```
document.getElementById(elID).scrollIntoView();
```

To jump to the element.

Comment: Yes, that's basically the approach I'm taking, and, as I say, I've made it work for almost everything I'm doing. One thing that's maybe a little different: our site actually has many identically structured pages, each of them operating on this principle, but with different page-specific content. Sorry if that's a bit cryptic, but we aren't in Beta yet, so I can't explain too much.

Comment: Oooh, interesting. I'll try that.